# Pass through '&parameter' in a URL

Tags: wordpress, iframe, parameters, url-parameters

I'm working on a project which passes a variable into a iFrame with this code:

```
jQuery(function() {
    var search = window.location.search;
    jQuery(".iframe-wrapper").attr("src", jQuery(".iframe-wrapper").attr("src")+search);
});
```

But, when I pass through `&section=P1` in a URL, it just gives a 404.

Source of the iFrame: `example.com/page?cart=1`

After going to `site.com/&section=P1` the iFrame should change to `example.com/page?cart=1&section=P1`

Anyway to pass through the `&section=P1` through the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please send your HTML as mine is working fine with the below:

```
  <iframe width="500" height="200" class="iframe-wrapper" src="http://www.google.com?param=1"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
    var search = window.location.search;
    search = search.replace("?","&");

    $(".iframe-wrapper").attr("src", $(".iframe-wrapper").attr("src")+search);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: As I said, the iFrame SRC has already a parameter on it, that's the problem, I only want to add `&section=P1` to the URL